# How do I calculate 95% CI for Krippendorf's Alpha in R?

Tags: r, reliability

I'm looking for guidance on how to calculate the 95% confidence intervals for Krippendorf's alpha coefficients in R. I've already calculated the coefficients:

```
key2 <- data.frame("rater1"=as.vector(t(rater1[2,])), "rater2"=as.vector(t(rater2[2,])))

key2 <- t(as.matrix(key2))
kripp.alpha(key2, method="ordinal")

Results: n=30, 2 raters, Alpha = 0.767
```

Previous forums suggesting conventional bootstrapping techniques don't seem to be the right course of action:

- [Bootstrapping Krippendorff's Alpha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952366/bootstrapping-krippendorffs-alpha)
- [How to compute confidence intervall for Krippendorf's Alpha in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944703/how-to-compute-confidence-intervall-for-krippendorfs-alpha-in-r)

Not sure if this is also helpful: http://web.asc.upenn.edu/usr/krippendorff/boot.c-Alpha.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Welcome newbie! A couple pointers:

1) Always include a reproducible example, if you can.  You can set a seed with set.seed(), then simulate some data, and post all your code here.
2) StackOverflow is more for coding questions, the companion site CrossValidated is for the theory questions - e.g. SO is where you'd ask how to do bootstrapping for this, and CV is where you'd ask if bootstrapping is appropriate.

I'd say bootstrapping is called for, Krippendorf actually wrote a short paper about it: http://web.asc.upenn.edu/usr/krippendorff/boot.c-Alpha.pdf

There's also this page for some implementations in R, if you haven't come across it already: http://agreestat.com/r_functions.html